# Manage freedesktop trashcan with dired mode

Tags: dired, files

Trashed files are stored in the FreeDesktop standard location:
~/.local/share/Trash/files. How do I restore or permanently delete files in that folder using dired?

Comment: I use the following two settings to control placing deleted files in a specific location:  `(setq delete-by-moving-to-trash t) (setq trash-directory "~/.Trash")`  To my knowledge, Emacs doesn't keep track of files that are trashed for purposes of restoration.  OSX has built-in support to restore from Finder.app.  The following link is to a library that deals with OSX related trash:  https://github.com/lunaryorn/osx-trash.el

Comment: Is it possible to read system files (app datas like pcmanfm) for the tracking information?

Comment: This might answer to your request ;-) https://github.com/shingo256/trashed

Comment: I've also found your trashed a few days ago on melpa. That's exactly what I am looling for. Thank you!

Comment: @ShingoTanaka Can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trashed in MELPA. This package provides you a simple but convenient user interface to manage trashed files. It supports both MS Windows Recycle Bin and freedesktop.org Trash Can.  See https://github.com/shingo256/trashed

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer, so it risks being deleted. Please add at least a summary of the info to be found at that link. Thx.

Comment: Thx for the heads up.  Done.